# I want to Add Hypen on first 3 Characters

Tags: vb.net, keyup

This is my problem. In KeyUp

```
If Textbox1.Text.Length = 3 Then

Textbox1.Text = Textbox1.Text.Insert(3, "-")

Textbox1.SelectionStart = Textbox1.TextLength

End If
```

The Output is like This:

```
AAA-0123
```

For example, I entered wrong on the first 3 letters and I want change it, But still i cant delete the hyphen

`AAA-`

Comment: You mean you use `Backspace`, if yes, when you press that, it will enter your function and add the `-` again, try to detect the key in your function

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?626118-License-Key-Serial-Code-TextBox&highlight=

Comment: You can always check if your key is not the `Backspace` key and execute the function on that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the `MaskedTextBox`? So you can only enter text in this format.

[Masked Textbox MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_MaskInputRejected(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MaskInputRejectedEventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.MaskInputRejected
    If (Me.MaskedTextBox1.MaskFull) Then
        ToolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Input Rejected - Too Much Data"
        ToolTip1.Show("You cannot enter any more data into the date field. Delete some characters in order to insert more data.", Me.MaskedTextBox1, Me.MaskedTextBox1.Location.X, Me.MaskedTextBox1.Location.Y, 5000)
    ElseIf (e.Position = Me.MaskedTextBox1.Mask.Length) Then
        ToolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Input Rejected - End of Field"
        ToolTip1.Show("You cannot add extra characters to the end of this date field.", Me.MaskedTextBox1, 0, -20, 5000)
    Else
        ToolTip1.ToolTipTitle = "Input Rejected"
        ToolTip1.Show("You can only add numeric characters (0-9) into this date field.", Me.MaskedTextBox1, 0, -20, 5000)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ToolTip1.IsBalloon = True
    Me.MaskedTextBox1.Mask = "00/00/0000"
End Sub

Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.KeyDown
    ' The balloon tip is visible for five seconds; if the user types any data before it disappears, collapse it ourselves.
    Me.ToolTip1.Hide(Me.MaskedTextBox1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is realy depending on how you are editing your string. Anyway this mught be what you are looking for:

```
     Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If TextBox1.Text.Length = 3 And e.KeyCode <> Keys.Back Then
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Insert(3, "-")
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.TextLength
    End If
End Sub
```